# Procedure or Function expects parameter which is not supplied even though it is?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql

Not sure if I'm calling this incorrectly but I'm receiving an error saying I'm not providing a parameter. I attempt to execute the stored procedure using LINQ to SQL as follows:

```
Context.ExecuteQuery(returnType, "EXEC [GetResults]", new object[] {StoredProcName});
```

I also tried calling it like this but it gave me a syntax error (since the SP is in another database I have to provide the full name):

```
Context.ExecuteQuery(returnType, string.Format("EXEC [GetResults]{0}", storedProcName));
```

StoredProcName is set to this value: [DevDB].[Services].[GetTypes]

Is it not possible to pass it in that way?

Comment: shouldn't that stored proc already mapped to a method you can call?

Comment: Normally it would be in a dbml file but this one stored proc is actually calling a stored procedure so the return type is not always the same. I'm generating the return type during run time in another part of my app so that's why I am doing it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow I just figured it out, I feel really silly now. I was reading the function definition wrong.
It should have been called this way:

```
Context.ExecuteQuery(returnType, "EXEC [GetResults]{0}", storedProcName);
```